# Deleting HTML tags with vim

Tags: html, vim, vi

How can I easily delete blocks of text surrounded by HTML tags?

Say I come across a block of text that is surrounded by `<div>` tags. How can I easily delete everything within the tags, and the tags themselves, all at once?

Comment: Is this *block of text* somehow delimited? Does it contain nested `<div>` tags?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Text objects are your friends...

- `dat` : "delete around tag"
- `dit` : "delete inside tag"

There are also similar operations for changing the text (`cat` and `cit`) and selecting it visually (`vat` and `vit`).

Have fun!

Comment: `ci(  change inner bracket`
`ci"  change inner quotation marks`
`vip  visual select inner paragraph`
`and so on`

Answer (score 9):

When in the `<div>`, say, you can do `dat`